# Get value of an element in nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know this might have been asked a number of times. but in my case i get this error by using this

```
echo $result["tracks"]["title"];
```

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\withheader.php on line 26

and by using `print_r ($result);` I get the following result

I want to get the result of array tracks and the element title. so ideally the output should be a variable with value `DHL (Deprecated)`

```
stdClass Object ( [increment_id] => 100000045 [store_id] => 1 [created_at] => 2015-09-07 07:34:06 [updated_at] => 2015-09-18 06:02:02 [shipping_address_id] => 441 [order_id] => 224 [total_qty] => 2.0000 [shipment_id] => 48 [items] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [parent_id] => 48 [sku] => testsimpleadmin [name] => testsimpleadmin [order_item_id] => 642 [product_id] => 57050 [weight] => 2.0000 [price] => 100.0000 [qty] => 1.0000 [item_id] => 96 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [parent_id] => 48 [sku] => 12121221 [name] => women fancy bag [order_item_id] => 643 [product_id] => 57090 [weight] => 1.0000 [price] => 71.0000 [qty] => 1.0000 [item_id] => 97 ) ) [tracks] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [parent_id] => 48 [created_at] => 2015-09-18 06:02:02 [updated_at] => 2015-09-18 06:02:02 [carrier_code] => dhl [title] => DHL (Deprecated) [number] => 456 [order_id] => 224 [track_id] => 5 ) ) [comments] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: It is an object not an array.

Comment: `echo $result->tracks[0]->title`

Comment: Thanks Uchiha, exactly what i was looking for..
You may add this is an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from your `print_r($result)` its an `object` and not an `array`. So instead of calling it like as

```
echo $result["tracks"]["title"];
```

you need to use

```
echo $result->tracks[0]->title
```

Comment: Also can you help me to get the Item name and SKU for the items under the array **items**

Comment: `echo $result->tracks[0]->sku`. If you need the values of each array objects you can simply loop it using `foreach($result->tracks as $val) { echo $val->sku;}`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `$result` is not an array but an `Object`.

So you have to access `$result` like you would do with a normal object with `->`.
From your `print_r` we can see that the attribute `tracks`is an array with just one element in it. So by doing `$result->tracks[0]->title` should work

Comment: Oh sorry, just saw now the comments in the question...